# Sql insertion of column with calculated value. Error subqueries are not allowed in this context

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, alter-table

I'm trying to run this query, but I'm receiving this error:

> Error subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

```
 Alter Table dbo.factures_wtd ADD [WTD] AS (
 
 Select dbo.factures_wtd.facture, dbo.factures_wtd.date_facture, dbo.factures_wtd.prix,
  WTD = SUM(dbo.factures_wtd.prix)
  OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.factures_wtd.facture, YEAR(dbo.factures_wtd.date_facture), MONTH(dbo.factures_wtd.date_facture), DATEPART(WEEK,dbo.factures_wtd.date_facture) ORDER BY dbo.factures_wtd.date_facture ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
 FROM dbo.factures_wtd )
```

I want to add a column of WTD data, from other columns.

Comment: You don't. `CREATE` a `VIEW`. Though you *could* create a scalar function, these can actually be *terrible* for performance.

Comment: I need good performance in this specific project. Thanks!

Comment: Then use a `VIEW`.

Comment: Also, as an FYI, [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: Done, but still having the same issue

Comment: You *can't* get the error with a `VIEW`.

Comment: If you see my cod below, i have and ORDER BY, those aren't supported in a VIEW